# Как получить категории товаров WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как правильно составить запрос к `WP_Query` на получение категорий товаров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не нужен WP_Query(), который используется для цикла по постам или товарам. Используйте такой код:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
);
$terms = get_terms( $args );
```